# Is it right to use create action without primarily invoking the new action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it right to handle all of the object creation logic inside `create` action without touching the `new` action? Why even bother with `new`?

```
def create
  item = Item.new item_params
  item.save
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not required.

The `new` method is literally to render an HTML page that contains a form to create a new object.

You don't need to implement `new` (or `edit`), for example, if you are using Rails only for a JSON API.

Another example where you might not need it (in a traditional Rails app), is when the form to create the "new" object is rendered by some other controller/view.

Comment: I'm indeed using rails for JSON api, thanks for the answer. One question though, is it a good practice to use `new` solely for breaking down the complexity of logic and for better testability?

Comment: It really has no function in a JSON API because your client app is rendering  the form to create the new object. So the server only has to worry about accepting the POST/PUT from the client (via `create`/`update`).